# How can I do this complex foreign-key query in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: mysql, database, sqlalchemy

I have the following 3 SQL Alchemy models

```
class MyModelA(db.Model):
    a_id   = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    my_field1 = db.Column(db.String(1024), unique=True)

class MyModelB(db.Model):
    b_id   = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    my_field2 = db.Column(db.String(1024), nullable=True)

    def my_method(self, arg_my_field1):
        pass # what goes here??

class MyModelC(db.Model, Timestamp):
    c_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    a_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(MyModelA.a_id), default=lambda: MyModelA.query.filter(MyModelA.my_field1 == 'XYZ').one().a_id)
    a = db.relationship('MyModelA', backref=db.backref('my_model_c'))
    b_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(MyModelB.b_id), nullable=False)
    b = db.relationship('MyModelB', backref=db.backref('my_model_c'))
    my_field3 = db.Column(db.String(1024), unique=True)
    __table_args__ = (db.UniqueConstraint('a_id', 'b_id', name='unique_constraint_aid_bid'),)
```

In the method `my_method`, I want to return the `my_field3` field of the instance of `MyModelC` that (points to `self` and points to the `MyModelA` that has `my_field1==arg_my_field1`). There should be maximum one such instance. If no such instance of `MyModelC` exists return `None`. How can I write that method?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer

```
def my_method(self, arg_my_field1):
    return self.my_model_c.join(MyModelA).filter(MyModelA.my_field1.ilike(arg_my_field1)).one().my_field3
```

It requires `lazy='dynamic'` to be added to the two relationships in `MyModelC` as shown below:

```
class MyModelC(db.Model, Timestamp):
    c_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    a_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(MyModelA.a_id), default=lambda: MyModelA.query.filter(MyModelA.my_field1 == 'XYZ').one().a_id)
    a = db.relationship('MyModelA', backref=db.backref('my_model_c', lazy='dynamic'))
    b_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(MyModelB.b_id), nullable=False)    # MODIFIED
    b = db.relationship('MyModelB', backref=db.backref('my_model_c', lazy='dynamic'))    # MODIFIED
    my_field3 = db.Column(db.String(1024), unique=True)
    __table_args__ = (db.UniqueConstraint('a_id', 'b_id', name='unique_constraint_aid_bid'))
```